# When I submit my form_tag, nothing happened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm currently trying to implement a search bar for places which are associates to my client table.

When i push enter, I want my page to select all the places who match with the input.

My form_tag looks like this :

```
= form_tag (@client_place_path), method: :get do
  = text_field_tag :query,
  params[:query],
  placeholder: "Find a place"
```

My places controller :

```
if params[:query].present?
  @places_search = Place.where("email ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")
else 
  @places = Place.all
end
```

my routes

```
resources :places do
  delete 'destroy_image', to: 'places#destroy_image'
  # get 'visits', to: 'visits#index'
  # delete 'visits/reset', to: 'visits#reset'
end
```

and the rakes routes looks like this :

```
client_places GET    /client/places(.:format)                                         client/places#index
              POST   /client/places(.:format)                                         client/places#create
new_client_place GET    /client/places/new(.:format)                                     client/places#new
edit_client_place GET    /client/places/:id/edit(.:format)                                client/places#edit
client_place GET    /client/places/:id(.:format)                                     client/places#show
             PATCH  /client/places/:id(.:format)                                     client/places#update
             PUT    /client/places/:id(.:format)                                     client/places#update
             DELETE /client/places/:id(.:format)
```

So when I try to get something, my view stays the same but the url looks like `http://localhost:3000/client/places?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=#{Place.name}`

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if params[:query].present?
  @places_search = Place.where("email ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")
else 
  @places = Place.all
end
```

well form works right it send u back to same page with get request but 
@places search should be @places
ALSO IN QUERY ILIKE should be LIKE

Comment: I did that, and indeed, it send me back to the same page. But no data are present .. Do you have any idea where that could come from?

Comment: Change ILIKE to LIKE

Comment: I did that, but still the same ... I saw that I had to put ILIKE for postgresql and deployment

Comment: does any email match any part of your query u searching?
Also where u display your searches or want to display.. do u want to display them same page as your form is?

Comment: Oh my god ... You just saved my entire night. I was looking for name and I put email ... Thanks a lot for your time !